# How can I see why a file isn't compiling somewhere else, if it does in my machine?

Tags: hyperref, errors, compiling, document-classes, elsarticle

I'm attempting to submit a paper using the Elsevier Editorial System in LaTeX, and in the final step before submission it builds a file with information, the cover letter, and hopefully the manuscript, except it says it will include text from the console if it fails to build. Even though the file compiles with no trouble on my computer, it won't properly build the manuscript. I tried making minor adjustments to make it in the `elsarticle` class, to no avail.

Any suggestions for how reading the console will help figure out what goes wrong? Somethings that caught my eye were:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Wrong driver `hpdftex.def`;
No file header.tex.
 (./cofeesub.aux) 
\openout1"
File: dvips.def1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependentfile (DPC,SPQR)
! Incompatible list can't be unboxed.
```

Even so, I don't have any idea how to analyze or fix these issues (if they are), so any help would be appreciated. I'd post related files, but I don't know how.

Comment: Cut things out of your paper and resubmit it. If the error goes away, don't complete the submission -- now you know that something you cut was part of the problem. Keep cutting things that don't cause the error, and leaving things in that do, until you have a minimal example that fails.

Comment: Are you using the [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) with a fixed driver setting? That is, you have something like `\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}` in your preamble? `hyperref` will automatically detect the given driver, so you can drop this from the package options.

Comment: If using `pdflatex` in `pdf` mode when you compile on your own machine, try adding `%&pdflatex` to the first line of the `.tex` file you upload. (May help others with the same problem.)

Answer (score 5):

The first line tells you that you are giving hyperref the wrong option `pdftex`. Remove it as Werner wrote.

The `! Incompatible list can't be unboxed.` was quite frequent about two years ago (which probably means that the editorial system uses an quite old LaTeX) and was at that time related to hyperref + pgf (tikz). You could try to add `\usepackage{atbegshi}` before loading pgf or tikz.