# error related to amsmath with latex but not pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, amsmath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I see why a file isn't compiling somewhere else, if it does in my machine?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40716/how-can-i-see-why-a-file-isnt-compiling-somewhere-else-if-it-does-in-my-machin)

I am getting a bunch of

```
! Incompatible list cannot be unboxed
```

resulting from the `align` environment of [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) if I compile with `latex`.

However if I use `pdflatex` my output is produced without any problems. I would like to use [psfrag](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) for some figures, so I need to compile with `latex`. Is there an easy workaround for this problem? Or more importantly what is the reason of this problem?

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example? Thank you.

Comment: I had again time to look at this problem, the problem comes from the use of \stackrel or \overset commands in the align environment of amsmath. More specifically, I try to use citations for some equations in \overset or \stackrel as such \overset{\ref{eq1}}{=}