# Is it blkarray compatible with beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer, arrays

When I try next code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
        \begin{frame}{Title}

            \[
            \begin{blockarray}{c|c}
            A & B 
            \end{blockarray}
            \]      
        \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

pdflatex finishes with

```
 ! Incompatible list can't be unboxed. <argument> \BA@first@box 
                           l.15         \end{frame}
```

If I replace `beamer` with `article` there is no problem. Do you know why?

Comment: Maybe related : [how-can-i-see-why-a-file-isnt-compiling-somewhere-else-if-it-does-in-my-machine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40716/how-can-i-see-why-a-file-isnt-compiling-somewhere-else-if-it-does-in-my-machin/40732#40732)

Comment: @percusse: That might be related, but the suggest workaround won't help.  `tikz` is loaded with the `beamer` documentclass so there's no way to load `atbegshi` first.  At least, that's what I found when I tried to compile the original poster's MWE.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Indeed, it's not working. But I was hoping to find something  that `blkarray` does similar to the case that is not valid anymore.

Comment: @percusse: I've tested with `\RequirePackage{atbegshi}` before `\documentclass{beamer}` but the problem persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`blkarray` has two implementations a "quick" version for simple arrays and the full version if you want to do all the weird things that the package allows. For some reason eluding me at present `beamer` doesn't like the quick version so you can add to the document preamble after loading `blkarray`.

```
\makeatletter
\let\BA@quicktrue\BA@quickfalse
\makeatother
```

then it seems to work OK. Even the slow version is a lot quicker than the quick version was in 1992:-)

Answer (score 8):

You need a `block` environment within your `blkarray` environment, similar to the one given in [Error with blkarray: Misplaced \noalign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34355/error-with-blkarray-misplaced-noalign):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cc}
A & B \\
\begin{block}{c[c]}
1 & 2 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]      
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you spot that:-) To be more exact you just need to force blkarray to avoid its "quick" code. See my answer below, but +1 from me as the hint saved a fair bit of debugging time.

Comment: The actual thought process was: first, read the other comment's linked answer, and write a long (unposted) comment about how the OP probably needed to update their TeX system, and not to take the posted solution so literally. Second, see that the MWE didn't work in my updated TeX Live, and cancel the previous comment. Third, Googled 'beamer blkarray' in case someone else had a similar problem, and found Stefan's answer. Fourth, verified Stefan's answer worked in the MWE, and happily avoided thinking about other methods.

Comment: Of course, not knowing `blkarray` or what the OP was really trying to accomplish, my answer may miss the point entirely.

Comment: @MikeRenfro: I wanted to write an answer to [using multiple brace in array environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54914/1952) with `blkarray`. The OP used `beamer` so I did the same and found the problem. I also googled and found Stefan`s answer but I didn't related with my error.